# foreach to foreach array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update specific data of an array that is being displayed thru ng-repeat.

Given the datas:

```
$scope.cartItems = [];
$scope.items = [{code: 'ABC', cash:'20.00', charge: '25.00'},
{code: 'DEF', cash:'10.00', charge: '15.00'},{code: 
'GHI',cash:'30.00', charge: '35.00'}];
```

then i have this table

```
Item | Price | Action
ABC  | 20.00 | Add
DEF  | 10.00 | Add

ng-click="add(Item,Price)"
$scope.add = function(Item,Price){
var itemscart = {};
itemscart.code = Item;
itemscart.price = Price;

$scope.cartItems.push(itemscart)
}
```

and is being displayed like this thru html table.

```
ng-repeat="cart in cartItems"
Item | price | bracket
ABC  | 20.00 | Cash //dropdown
DEF  | 10.00 | Cash //dropdown
```

And i have this dropdown select tag with option value; "Cash" or "Charge"

If in the dropdown i selected charge. The expected output of the html table must be:

```
Item | price | braket
ABC  | 25.00 | Charge //dropdown
DEF  | 15.00 | Charge //dropdown
```

I have tried:

```
if($scope.optionval == 'Charge'){
  var price = 0;
  $scope.cartItems.forEach(function(v){
    if(v.code == ($scope.items.forEach(function(c){c.code; price = 
c.charge; }))) 
      v.PRICE = price;
    console.log(v.PRICE) //gets the last row
    console.log(price) //null


  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your displayed and expected table, you can try something like:

- On change of CASH to CHARGE, make a function call on ng-change in
  which pass the selected object with selected 'braket'.
- Then in function call you can filter data.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you could use a different approach, like using [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directives to get the results you are trying to achieve

Try adding a custom field in your $scope in order to store which price should be shown, then you have two choices: to modify every field or separately:

*Display independiently:*

**app.js**

```
$scope.items = [{code: 'ABC', cash:'20.00', charge: '25.00', displaying:'cash'},{...}
```

**HTML**

```
 <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

<tr ng-repeat="cart in whatever">
   <td>{{cart.item}}</td>
   <td ng-show="cart.displaying=='cash'>{{cart.cash}}</td>
   <td ng-show="cart.displaying=='charge'>{{cart.charge}}</td>
   <td>{{cart.displaying}}</td>
   <td>*Dropdown to modify this specific 'displaying' field*</td>
</tr>
```

*Every field at the same time:*

**app.js**

```
$scope.displayingitems = 'cash'
```

**HTML**

```
*Dropdown to modify this specific 'displaying' field*

 <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

<tr ng-repeat="cart in whatever">
   <td>{{cart.item}}</td>
   <td ng-show="displayingitems=='cash'>{{cart.cash}}</td>
   <td ng-show="displayingitems =='charge'>{{cart.charge}}</td>
   <td>{{displayingitems}}</td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```